# Handling JSON object from Twitter API response

Tags: php, json, rest, api, twitter

I'd like to retrieve all Twitter IDs of users that follow a certain other user (e.g. @Google) through the Twitter API. While the request works in Postman, I cannot get it working in PHP. It seems that $userids is not a string, so json_decode cannot process it. Code below. Thanks for your help!

```
<?php
require "twitteroauth/autoload.php";

use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');

$consumerKey = 'redacted';
$consumerKeySecret = 'redacted';
$accessToken = 'redacted';
$accessTokenSecret = 'redacted';
$cursor = -1; // first page

$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerKeySecret, $accessToken, $accessTokenSecret);
$content = $connection->get("account/verify_credentials");

$userids = $connection->get("followers/ids", ["cursor" => -1, "screen_name" => "google", "count" => 5000]);

echo $userids;

$data = json_decode($userids);
foreach ($data as $ids => $value) {
    // tbd
}
var_dump($data);

?>
```

Comment: So what is actual behaviour of the code? "It seems that `$userids` is not a string" - can you check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$userids is an array, as you can see in the TwitterOAuth source:

```
$response = JsonDecoder::decode($result, $this->decodeJsonAsArray);
```

That means you don't have to json_decode() it again, as it's already a PHP array.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks! I'm now trying to go through every User ID that is saved in the array and the cursor (which is at the very end of the response) to save those in the database. Before I bring in the DB complexity I just wanted to echo the ids to see if it works. However, when I use the following code: `for ($i=0; $i<=5000; $i++) {
    echo "<pre>"; echo $userids["ids"]; echo "</pre>"; 
}` I get the following error: `Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/fetchusers.php on line 35` --- Probably a trivial mistake, but I'm stuck. Thx!

Comment: Edit: resolved. $userids apparently is an object of the StdClass, which then contains(!) the array "ids". So the solution was `echo $userids->ids[5];` to get for example id number 5 and `echo $userids->next_cursor;` to get the cursor property.

Comment: If you ever want to know which type a variable is, you can always use `gettype($var)`.